# How to know backup file version

Tags: backup, version, firebird

I have a backup of a firebird database. I would know which version of gbak has made it and which version of firebird comes from.

Is it possible know this information?

PS: I googled a lot but I don't found a solution; the only workaround I found is try to restore with different version of *firebird* and *gbak*

Comment: Do you actually need the specific Firebird version, or do you just want to restore it?

Comment: I just want restore the backup without try with different version of firebird and gbak

Answer (score 1):

The `gbak` utility of a Firebird version will be able to read all backup formats of earlier versions (in theory since InterBase 4.0, although that isn't tested anymore). So if you want to restore a backup just use the latest version of Firebird to restore the file.

Also if you need to restore to an earlier Firebird version, you can use the `gbak` of the latest Firebird. When restoring to an older Firebird version it is capable of restoring a new backup format to an older server (although if the backup contains features of newer Firebird versions those parts will not be restored or the backup might fail, and you will also need to recompile all stored procedures).

The only potential snag is if the backup was from a different endian system, and the backup was not made transportable (the default is transportable though).

Comment: I need restore the backup to the same older version of Firebird. I try to use the latest gbak with an older version of firebird but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, here is where my `gbak` knowledge ends :( You might want to try the Firebird-support mailinglist as well (see http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/)

Comment: @MarcoAndreolli, you may check ATT_BACKUP_FORMAT constant in header of the backup file (if backup is transportable, ie stored in XDR). This const store backup version (more exactly FEATURE version that backup file MAY contain (ie new keywords, new sintaxis)). BUT most interesting thing, even if backup version is diffirent, backup CAN be restored on older versions of FB, if these new features are not used in database. Also, as I sad version backup is not related to FB version, for example, FB 1.0 and FB 1.5 have exactly the same backup version.

Comment: It seems that `gbak -z <a database file> <the backup file>` should also specify the ODS of the backup, but the documentation isn't really clear if it will actually return the ODS of the actual database or of the backup.

Comment: gbak -z switch just output gbak, firebird and database ods version

Answer (score 0):

Usually Firebird backups are stored in [External Data Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) (XDR) format.

That means file contain only XDR backup version, not Firebird version or even Gbak version. Backup version is not directly related to Firebird version.

Also, XDR backup is back FB version compatible. If your DB doesn't have any new specific FB features, you may downgrade it freely by restoring it using old version gbak.

Comment: That is not entirely correct, although gbak uses XDR to store the data, it does store the gbak backup format version in the header (the format version is related to the ODS features of Firebird)

Comment: Checked Gbak source. Just XDR backup version is stored. ATT_BACKUP_FORMAT constant.